# Can't I use an enum at application level if I have a NxN relationship?

Tags: java, database, enum

After reading the answers to [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/305148/why-would-you-store-an-enum-in-db) question, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152787/persisting-set-of-enums-in-a-many-to-many-unidirectional-mapping) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229856/ways-to-save-enums-in-database) related questions, I'm now confused about how/if to work with an enum having an NxN relationship.

Let's say I have an entity `Hotel`, an my hotels can offer some services: sauna, gym, wifi, etc. Following

> You should decide whether your Platform is an entity or not. If it's
>   an entity, it can't be an enum

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3153172/3748908), and

> The set of valid values is data, not code

From [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/305153/116408), and if I understood it all correctly, my approach to modelling this with the enum in DB is to have a `hotels` table, a `services` table, and a junction table `hotels_services`. The services table would have two columns `(id, service)` or just one `(service)`. When saving hotel information, the validity of the services would be enforced not by the application but by the DB. My `Service` class would then have two (`Long id, String service`) or just one (`String service/value`) fields. My `Hotel` class would have a `List<Service> services`.

So far, kind of good. But if my application's logic depends somehow on the type of service, I would like to have the enum's type safety. That looks hard, because then I would have to convert them to a `ServiceEnum` enum, which sounds just wrong: somewhere I would need to do the convertion, and there I would need to hardcode the possible values, so duplicity. Then, I have this extra class `ServiceEnum` that is confusing.

Is this how it's supposed to be? Just give up on using an enum in this case? I can live with it, but I'd like to hear that I need to, or what is it that people do in these cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing two ideas.  The relationship between `Hotel`'s and `Service`'s is going to either be one-to-many or many-to-many according to whether `Hotel` objects have *ownership* over a `Service` or if `Service`'s will be commonly shared amongst all `Hotel`'s.  You can do it in either way, since they both have pluses and minuses, but the important thing to note is that you could have a potentially unlimited amount of `Service`'s associated with a `Hotel`.

Today, you have "Room service", "Pool", and "Laundry service" to choose from and tomorrow you'll have "Room service", "Pool", "Laundry service", and "Parking".  While you could represent this with enum, it is likely best that you do not.  Keep in mind that entries in the `Service` table now only have a name, but you may later want to add other fields.  `Service` is just as much an entity as `Hotel` is, so it should be treated thusly.

In other words, you should have a `Service` class, and *not* an enum to handle `Service` instances.  Representing `Service` as a class not only represents that database table better, but it will make future maintenance much easier.  Adding say, localizations for each service is only a matter of adding a child table.  If you were handling it as an enum, you'd have to keep a static resource bundle that expands to represent new possible `ServiceEnum` values as you add them to your program, and though you wouldn't realize it, you'd essentially be trying to emulate `ServiceEnum` in your program *as if it were* a `Service` entity anyway.

It all boils down to properly representing this object in your program, and the best way to do that in this case is to treat it like any other entity.